# File Manipulation Loop

Tags: bash, unix, loops, awk

Ok, this question is two-fold: 1) The actual file manupulation bit 2) Looping this manipulation in unix

**Part 1)**

I have two files:

File_1

```
a b
c d
e f
g h
```

and File_2

```
A B
C D
E F
G H
I J
```

i would like to get (in the first instance) the following result:

```
a b
A B
>
c d
A B
>
e f
A B
>
g h
A B
```

...and save this output to outfile1.

I gather I would have to use things like *awk*, *cut* and/or *paste* but I can't manage to put it all together.

**Part 2)**

I then want to loop this manipulation for all rows in File_2 (note that the number of rows in File_1 is not the same as in File_2), such that I end up with 5 output files, where outfile2 would be:

```
a b
C D
>
c d
C D
>
e f
C D
>
g h
C D
```

and outfile3 would be:

```
a b
E F
>
c d
E F
>
e f
E F
>
g h
E F
```

etc.

At the moment I'm working in bash.  Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: I'm very new to coding in Unix, so at the moment the most complicated thing i can do is along the lines of `awk NR==51 { print $3, $4; exit }' < input` so my question is (basically) how do i process my input files to get my output files using Unix

Comment: PLease put your question [in your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/11578772/edit).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to make outfile_3(with E F) for example:

```
x=$(sed -n '3p' File_2)
awk "{ printf \"%s\\n%s\\n>\\n\", \$0, \"$x\" }" File_1 > outfile_3
```

in first line `'3p'` cuts 3-rd line
Now let's do it in a loop:

```
(( i = 1 ))
while read line
do
  awk "{ printf \"%s\\n%s\\n>\\n\", \$0, \"$line\" }" File_1 > "outfile_$i"
  (( i++ ))
done < File_2
```

Comment: Thank you!  This does exactly what I want.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done with `bash` redirection:

```bash
i=1

while read f2; do
  while read f1; do
    echo "$f1"
    echo "$f2"
    echo ">"
  done < File_1 | head -n -1 > output$i
  (( i++ ))
done < File_2
```

`head -n -1` avoids having a lone delimiter at the end of each `output$i` file.

Comment: Cleaner then mine, I just couldn't imagine nested loop in bash )))

Comment: I approve of this. Beware of performance issues. The perl solution will be a lot quicker, but that will only hurt if the files get large or the disks are slow :)

Comment: Indeed, this solution does not perform well on large input.

Comment: Thanks for answering - coming from a Matlab background this is the most intuitive answer for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
sort -m -f file1 file2 | uniq -i --all-repeated=separate
```

Looked rather close. However, on second reading I think you want something more like this perl script:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open(my $FILE1, '<file1') or die;

my $output = 0;

while (my $a = <$FILE1>)
{
    $output++;
    open(my $OUT, ">output$output");
    open(my $FILE2, '<file2') or die;

    print $OUT "$a$_---\n" foreach (<$FILE2>);

    close $FILE2;
    close $OUT;
}

close $FILE1;
```

This creates output files `output1`, `output12`, `output3`, `output...`, as many as there are lines in file1

Comment: A Perl-based solution for a question tagged with `bash` and `awk`...?

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer my questions, but as stakx intimated, this is not very useful for me - re-writing my scripts in perl is beyond me.

Comment: No need to rewrite stuff. I got the impression this was a new script. You can use it from bash, like awk :)

Answer (score 0):

an awk one liner:

```
     awk 'NR==FNR{a[NR]=$0;l=NR;next;} {b[FNR]=$0;}
    END{f=1; for(x=1;x<=FNR;x++){for(i=1;i<=length(a);i++){
printf "%s\n%s\n%s\n", a[i],b[x],">" > "output"f }f++;}}' f1 f2
```

test:

```
kent$  head f1 f2
==> f1 <==
a b
c d
e f
g h

==> f2 <==
A B
C D
E F
G H
I J


kent$  awk 'NR==FNR{a[NR]=$0;l=NR;next;} {b[FNR]=$0;}
END{f=1; for(x=1;x<=FNR;x++){for(i=1;i<=length(a);i++){printf "%s\n%s\n%s\n", a[i],b[x],">" > "output"f }f++;}}' f1 f2

kent$  head -30 out*
==> output1 <==
a b
A B
>
c d
A B
>
e f
A B
>
g h
A B
>

==> output2 <==
a b
C D
>
c d
C D
>
e f
C D
>
g h
C D
>

==> output3 <==
a b
E F
>
c d
E F
>
e f
E F
>
g h
E F
>

==> output4 <==
a b
G H
>
c d
G H
>
e f
G H
>
g h
G H
>

==> output5 <==
a b
I J
>
c d
I J
>
e f
I J
>
g h
I J
>
```

Comment: IMHO, your solution would be even better if you explained to the OP how and why it works, especially since he's "new to coding in Unix".

Comment: As much as I really want to like your answer, as stakx says, this is really difficult for me to deconstruct.  It also means that when I get an error (which I do): `awk: syntax error at source line 2
 context is
 END{f=1; for(x=1;x<=FNR;x++){for(i=1;i<=length(a);i++){printf "%s\n%s\n%s\n", a[i],b[x],">" > >>>  "output"f <<<  }f++;}}
awk: illegal statement at source line 2`

I don't know how to solve the problem.  Thanks anyway!